# How to loop over document.body in a function

Tags: javascript, dom

I have to write a version of getElementsByClassName but i'm having trouble using document.body in my function. It only returns null when called. I realize that the recursion part needs to be fixed and finished but first I'd like to know how to access document.body (along with its childNodes) and use it in a function. Or maybe I'm approaching it the wrong way?

```
var getElementsByClassName = function() {

  var bod = document.body;

  
  for (var i = 0; i < bod.childNodes.length; i++) {
    var thisNode = bod.childNodes[i];
    var classTest = bod.childNodes[i].className;
    if (classTest === classname) {
    }
    //recursion here
    if (thisNode.childNodes.length > 0) {
      getElementsByClassName();
    }
  }

};
```

Comment: why would you need to write your own function? `querySelectorAll` would help you with anything related to css classes

Comment: `document.body` can be `undefined` when you didn't wait for DOM to load.

Comment: ...but if you do want to... make the `element` an argument passed into `getElementsByClassName(element)`, start with the `document.body` then pass in each `thisNode` that has childNodes.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski if you didn’t wait for the DOM to load, your own function would fail as well… and you can call `querySelectorAll` on any DOM element rather than just document.body… I still don’t get the point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the `getElementsByClassName()` function an argument of `element` and pass in each node that you want to recurse. Note that you can also use `querySelectorAll()` instead of writing your own.

```
var getElementsByClassName = function (element) {
  for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
    var thisNode = element.childNodes[i];
    var classTest = thisNode.className;
    if (classTest === classname) {
    }
    //recursion here
    if (thisNode.childNodes.length > 0) {
      getElementsByClassName(thisNode);
    }
  }
};

getElementsByClassName(document.body);
```

Comment: I‘d still discourage anyone to create their own implementation. If the DOM is deep enough, you run into recursion limits which may be much lower than you might expect. stick to querySelectorAll